# Is orthogonal polygon with crossings count NP-complete?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-complexity, computational-geometry

The are several NP-complete problems related to the construction of orthogonal simple polygons. Rapport showed that it is NP-complete to decide the existence of orthogonal simple polygon that passes through given grid points (polygon’s vertices) such that the angles at those points are either 90, 270 or 180 degrees.

I’m interested in non-simple orthognal polygons (it may cross itself).

Input: Given angles sequence at the vertices ( S= [L,R,R, …] where L= 90 degrees and R=270 degrees)
and crossings count N

Problem: Decide the existence of orthogonal complex polygon with given angles sequence S and crossings count N?

Is this problem NP-complete? Is it solvable by polynomial-time algorithm?

Here is a solution for the input [R,L,L,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,R,L,L,R,R,R,L,L,R] and crossings count 14.

[image: Here is a solution for the input [R,L,L,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,R,L,L,R,R,R,L,L,R] and crossings count 15]

Comment: Early version was posted without an answer  on TCS Stackexhange: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51838/is-orthogonal-polygon-with-crossings-count-np-complete

Comment: This recent paper includes an historical summary of related problems: Evans, William S., Noushin Saeedi, Chan-Su Shin, and Hyun Tark. "Reachability of turn sequences." [arXiv:2203.00855](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.00855) (2022). For simple polygons, "A turn sequence can be realized ... if and only if the number of left and right turns in the sequence differs by exactly four." Perhaps there has been less study of self-crossing polygons.

Comment: If you relax the angle restrictions so left means 0 to 180 and right means 180 to 360, then the realizability problem is hard for the existential theory of the reals (any number of crossings allowed). This is Corollary 2 in [On the Complexity of Some Geometric Problems With Fixed Parameters](https://jgaa.info/accepted/2021/557.pdf).